# select radio button based on dropdown selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In the below code, if I select try1,it should search db and display corresponding value in input box as well as radio button. Here input box value is displayed correctly but radio button is not working. Need help

**Script:**

```
$("#test1").change(function()
    {
        $.post('test_file.php', {test_name: $(this).val() },
        function(opt){
        $("#name33").val(opt.test_code);
        $('#ok').val(opt.test_code2);
        }, 'json');

    });
```

**Html:**

```
<table><tr>
<td>
<select name="test1" id="test1" >
<option >try1</option>
<option >try2</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name33" id="name" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="ok" id="ok" value="ok"/>ok
<input type="radio" name="ok" id="ok" value="not_ok"/>Not ok                
</td>
```

**test_file.php**

```
$db_sql = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM client WHERE test_name='".$_POST['test_name']."'" );
$test_code1=$db_sql->name;
$test_code2=$db_sql->try;

if($db_sql!=NULL)
{
$arr = array ("test_code1"=>"$test_code1","test_code2"=>"$test_code2");
echo json_encode($arr);
}
else
{
$arr1 = array ("no"=>"no");
echo json_encode($arr1);

}
```

Comment: What is in `test_code2` ?

Comment: the value of radio button(ok or not_ok) which is fetched from database from the field 'try'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if(opt.test_code2=="ok")
{
  $('input:radio[value=ok]').prop("checked",true);
}
else if(opt.test_code2=="not_ok")
{
  $('input:radio[value=not_ok]').prop("checked",true);
}
```

Instead Of

```
$('#ok').val(opt.test_code2);
```

> Because you set only value using `.val()` function and `id` of radio button is not unique so you have to take `radio value` as selector. If you want to checked your radio button according to its value then you have to use `.prop()` function.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vofpr7th/1/)**

Comment: Please check the html part now. i have updated. Am sry, the names and id are same in both radio button, then only one radio button will be selected.

Comment: Where is `drop-down`?